# fstream directly access struct variable

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

I know how to read and write a complete struct with fstream. But just for curiosity, is there a way to access (read or write) a variable directly? I have never seen somebody doing this.

```
aStruct * dummyStruct = 0;
int num = 7;

File.seekp(streamPosition, ios::beg);
File.seekp((unsigned long long)&(dummyStruct->aVariable), ios::cur);

File.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&num), sizeof(num));
```

Has anybody done something like this?

Comment: I would recommend using [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) instead for the `seekp` call, but it's certainly doable. And if you only want to write that single variable (and the variable is the exact same size as in the structure) then I see no problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetof` to determine the offset location of the variable.

```
File.seekp(offsetof(aStruct, aVariable), ios::cur);
```

Comment: And the pointer? It looks weired for me to make a null pointer and take  a sub pointer of it. It works of course.

Comment: Sorry, I missed you were assigning a null pointer value. All you need to change is the line that does the seek then read into `num`.